# Disable Clang Tool diagnostics

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, llvm, llvm-clang

This will be a general question. I am currently writing a tool for `clang` which is related to AST traversal. So I have a `frontendaction` to create an `ASTConsumer` which, further, has a `RecursiveASTVistor`. I call `Tool.run()` to execute my action. It runs fine but clang by default prints out all the warnings and errors in the repo I try to analyze. Is there anyway I can disable clang diagnostics? I know that when we compile with clang, the `-w` option all disable diagnostics. But How do we do that for a tool? By the way, my tool resides in `/llvm/tools/clang/tools/extra/mytool`

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [IgnoringDiagConsumer](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1IgnoringDiagConsumer.html) which suppresses all diagnostic messages:

```
class MyFrontendAction : public ASTFrontendAction
{
public:
    MyFrontendAction() {}

    std::unique_ptr<ASTConsumer> CreateASTConsumer(CompilerInstance &CI, StringRef file) override
    {
        CI.getDiagnostics().setClient(new IgnoringDiagConsumer());
        return llvm::make_unique<MyASTConsumer>();
    }
};
```

Or you can implement your own DiagnosticConsumer to handle diagnostics.

Another option is to pass `-w` option to your tool after `--` at command line to ignore warnings (error messages will not be suppressed, of course):

```
mytool.exe test.cpp -- -w
```